# PostgreSQL strange behaviour with array_to_json

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-13

I wanted to use array_agg to eliminate nulls before converting to JSON but the null reappears in the JSON output.
Here is a minimal example demonstrating the behaviour:

```
select id, array_agg(alias), array_to_json(array_agg(alias))
from (values (1, 'foo'), (1, 'bar'), (2, null)) t(id, alias)
group by id;
```

The resultset is this:

```
id|array_agg|array_to_json|
--+---------+-------------+
 1|{foo,bar}|["foo","bar"]|
 2|{}       |[null]       |
```

Comment: You could use `jsonb_agg(alias) filter (where alias is not null)`

Comment: Note that the `array_agg` isn't (or shouldn't be) removing the `null` value. Try running `\pset null (null)` before running this to see the null value.

Comment: Why not ` WHERE alias NOTNULL`?

Comment: Normally the nulls would come from a left join and I want an empty array for IDs which don't have a match in the joined table WHERE alias not null would remove the rows entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `array_agg` states that it "Collects all the input values, including nulls, into an array." The array appearing empty is simply how the output is formatted, but in reality it still contains `null`.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html

To get an empty array for the `null` values use `json_agg` with a `filter` clause and `coalesce`:

```
select 
  id,
  coalesce(json_agg(alias) filter (where alias is not null), '[]'::json)
from (values (1, 'foo'), (1, 'bar'), (2, null)) t(id, alias)
group by id;
```